# How to fix Sequelize auto + character "s" in model

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I define models with Sequelize and Nodejs but key i define is:

```
var User = fsdb.define("user", {...})
```

and in my database I was create table have name the same: "user"

but when run sequelize run sql is:

```
'SELECT `id`, `username`, `password`, `email`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `users` AS `user`;'
```

so this show error

```
  original: Error: Table 'sql6587389.users' doesn't exist
```

how to fix it
Thanks for any support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [freezeTableName option](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-basics/#enforcing-the-table-name-to-be-equal-to-the-model-name) when defining your model. In your case it would look like this:

```js
const User = fsdb.define("user", {...}, { freezeTableName: true });
```

From the linked documentation:

> You can stop the auto-pluralization performed by Sequelize using the `freezeTableName: true` option. This way, Sequelize will infer the table name to be equal to the model name, without any modifications: